# In_array but with more values

Tags: php, arrays

Example:

$array = array('hi', 'hello', 'bye');

How can I check if at least one of two or more values are present in the array ?

like:

if(in_array('hi', $array) || in_array('hello', $array)) ...

but with a single check? can it be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(count(array_intersect(array('hi','hello','bye'), $array))) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Or rather: `if(count(array_intersect(array('hi','hello','bye'), $array))>=2)`

Comment: No. He wants to return true if at least one is present, not if at least two are present.

Comment: +1 This is good. However, the counting is unnecessary. A non-empty array evaluated as boolean is always true.

Comment: Ah - right you are.  Dirty glasses.  I read "one or two or more", hence I thought he wanted to know how to frame his if conditions.  nm then.  +1 anyway, for a very quick response.  :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function in_array2($ary1,$ary2){
  return count(array_intersect($ary1,$ary2)) > 0;
}
```

Simple, make use of [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php), which will return entries in an array that match a predefined pattern (e.g. `'/^(hi|hello)$/` in your example).

E.g.

```
if (count(preg_grep('^/(hi|hello)$/',$array)))
{
  // your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use array_intersect()... i.e.

```
$array = array('hi', 'hello', 'bye');
if(count(array_intersect($array, array('search', 'for', 'values')))>0) ....
```